# What alternative is available to nth-child to select divs within other elements?

Tags: css

I have a HTML structure like so in my `<nav>`. I assumed `nth-child` was the way to go:

```
   <nav>
    <article class="menu-items">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="col-6 column">
        <!-- primary nav group one -->
        <li class="primary-nav">Home</li>
        <li class="primary-nav">News</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="col-6 column right align-right">
        <!-- primary nav group two -->
        <li class="primary-nav">About</li>
        <li class="primary-nav">Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <!-- primary nav group three -->
      <h1 class="primary-nav">Connect Online</h1>
      <ul class="col-6 column submenu-items">
        <li class="primary-nav"><a href="/">Twitter</a></li>
        <li class="primary-nav"><a href="/">Instagram</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="col-6 column right submenu-items align-right">
        <!-- primary nav group four -->
        <li class="primary-nav"><a href="/">Facebook</a></li>
        <li class="primary-nav"><a href="/">Sq</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </article>
 </nav>
```

And some CSS to trigger a transform after a delay

```
.primary-nav:nth-child(n) {
    transition-delay: 400ms;
}
.primary-nav:nth-child(2n) {
    transition-delay: 400ms;
}
.primary-nav:nth-child(3n) {
    transition-delay: 700ms;
}
.primary-nav:nth-child(4n) {
    transition-delay: 700ms;
}
.primary-nav:nth-child(5n) {
    transition-delay: 900ms;
}
/* and so on */
```

> MDN: The :nth-child() CSS pseudo-class matches one or more elements based on their position among a group of siblings

I can't use `nth-child` here because `primary-nav` are among different groups. When the end of the first group is reached, it will restart over. Makes sense. `(odd)` or `(even)` won't be much use here either.

How can I taget each `.primary-nav` div here? Can I do it without JS?

Comment: *"Can I do it without JS?"* - Unfortunately.. **NO**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if its a suitable solution for you but I think you can do this with Jquery.

```
var navDivs = $(".your-class-name").find(".primary-nav"); //Gives the list of divs who have the class .primary-nav.
```

Or, you can give an id to your div and search by ID

```
 var navDivs = $("#your-parent-div-id").find(".primary-nav"); //Gives the list of divs who have the class .primary-nav.
```

and finally by a for loop you can set any property of items by JQuery:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < navDivs.length; i++) {
  var div = navDivs[i];
  $(div).css("your-css-property", "your-css-value");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This will only apply one style/property to the div will it not?

Comment: css() methode can add only one property, you can call it more than one times. Or you can call  $(div).addClass("your-class-name"); And vice-versa  $(div).removeClass("your-class-name"); to remove a class.